# Using S3A client in EMR serverless

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I am using a S3 compatible object store (CloudFlare R2) and trying to get EMR serverless to connect to it. R2 requires that you use the correct endpoint and pass the secret key and access key.

In the local machine, running spark works perfectly fine. But when running it on EMR serverless it does not respect the params I try passing to it. To be precise, `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key`.

I've tried setting it in the application, as part of job from the console and as `--conf` in spark parameters, but it does not work.

Any ideas on how to go about this is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the EMR s3 connector -it's the one they support